# Proof exercise in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

I came up to this pretty complex analysis exercise where you need to apply most of the most famous theorems in a standard course.

Let $f :\mathbb{C} \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be an analytic injective function with $f(0)=0$

a) Let $r>0$. Prove that there exists $\epsilon >0$ such that $\forall z:|z|\geq r \Rightarrow |f(z)| \geq \epsilon$ 
b) Show that $g(z):=f(\frac{1}{z})$ has a pole in $z=0$ 
c) Prove that $f=Cz$ for some $C \in \mathbb{C}$

My thoughts: 
a) $|f(z)|$ is continuous as a composition of continuous functions. Since $\partial B_r(0)$ is a compact set, then $|f(z)|$ assumes a minimum on $\partial B_r(0)$, say $\varepsilon:=\underset{z \in \partial B_r(0)}{\min} |f(z)|>0$ by injectivity. By definition is the inequality satisfied on the circle. If we assume that $|f(z)|<\varepsilon$ for some $z$ with $|z|>r$, then $|f(z)|$ has a local maximum inside its domain and it is constant by the maximum principle, contradiction. 
b) The singularity is isolated, hence we can show that it cannot be essential or removable. If $g$ had an essential singularity at $z=0$, then $g(\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\} )=\mathbb{C}$ by Casorati-Weierstrass. By the open mapping theorem is the image of $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\} $ open in $\mathbb{C}$, but since $\mathbb{C}$ is closed, this is not possible. If it was removable, then $f$ would be bounded and hence constant by Liouville. 
c) By b) $g$ has a pole of order $k \in \mathbb{N}$, hence
$$g(z)=\dfrac{a_k}{z^k}+\dfrac{a_{k-1}}{z^{k-1}}+...+\dfrac{a_1}{z}+\Phi(z)$$ where $a_i$ are constants and $\Phi$ is holomorphic.
If $\Phi=0$, then $f(z)=g(\frac{1}{z})=a_kz^k+....+a_1z$. Since $f$ is injective, it follows with fundamental theorem of algebra that k=1.

I'm not sure how to show that $\Phi=0$ and that my proof is correct at all, especially b).

Comment: $b$ is not quite correct (Cassorati Weierstrass just says something about the closure of the image)  but $a$ implies that $|g(w)| \ge M, |w| \ge 1/r$ and that shows that the singularity is not essential; near a pole of order $m \ge 2$ the local form shows that the function looks like $cz^{-m}$ so the equation $f(z)=b$ has $m$ solutions for $|b|$ large enough (this can be done with estimates, with Rouche etc)